# Getting New York based company to delete my personal information

Tags: internet, privacy, new-york-state

I registered with Topresume.com and uploaded a copy of my resume. I found their service to be poor and according to the [Privacy Policy](https://www.topresume.com/privacy) they may sell information to third parties. Is there any laws in the state of New York I can use to my advantage to compel them to delete the data they have on me, for example if I write to them telling them to delete all data regarding me must they do so?

According to their Privacy Policy "if a child under 13 submits personal information to us and we learn that the personal information is the information of a child under 13, we will attempt to delete the information as soon as possible" so can I just lie and tell them I was 13?

Also, in there [terms (ToS)](https://www.topresume.com/terms) it states

> TopResume will provide the right to request and receive, once a year
>   and free of charge, information about third parties to whom we have
>   disclosed certain types of personal information (if any) about you for
>   our direct marketing purposes in the prior calendar year, and a
>   description of the categories of personal information shared. To make
>   such a request, please send an email to contact@topresume.com and
>   please include the phrase "Personal Information Privacy Request" in
>   the subject line, the domain name of the website you are inquiring
>   about, along with your name, address and email address. At our option,
>   we may respond to such requests by providing instructions about how
>   our users can exercise their options to prevent our disclosure of
>   personal information to third parties for their direct marketing
>   purposes.

Which to me sounds like it contains doublespeak but may mean they will not share information with third parties if they ask you to?

Comment: You may be interested in [Is a contract valid if one of the party doesn't even read it?](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/31843/20918). If Topresume.com did not prominently display the information or links to the information then there may not be a meeting of the minds.

Comment: One other thing you may be interested in... In Halvorson v. TalentBin, Inc. (Case No. 3:15-cv-05166-JCS) I believe California courts found the job sites that create profiles or dossiers and sell them to employers and recruiters are "credit reporters" and fall under the [Fair Credit Reporting Act (FCRA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_Credit_Reporting_Act). Not that FCRA is all that helpful... I read a scathing report from the Treasury Department several years ago about how ineffective FCRA is for consumers when the report contains inaccurate information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can't

You agreed:

> by submitting Materials in any form to the Company, in addition to other provisions of the Terms, you automatically grant Company a royalty-free, world-wide, **irrevocable**, non-exclusive, and **assignable** right and license to use, copy, reproduce, modify, adapt, publish, edit, translate, create derivative works from, transmit, distribute, publicly display and publicly perform such Materials for the purpose of displaying and promoting the Materials on any website operated by, and in any related marketing materials produced by, the Company and its affiliates.

They can keep and use your data forever and give it to whoever they want.

The clause you quote doesn't alter that. All it says is that once a year, if you ask, they will tell you what information they shared and with whom. If they feel like it they will tell you how to get the information deleted.